# When Configurable swatches enabled, thumbnails not loading picture to main

Tags: configurable-swatches, magento-1.9.4.0

I have an issue with magento 1.9.4

When i enable configurable swatches the thumbnails not load picture in the main but on click it goes to top of page.

Do anyone know what file or template is enabled with Configurable swatches to try re-install or debug them?

On fresh installation it work. It is something wrong on my app. This magento installation is started with 1.8, many updates are installed....

Comment: just link to same page, with url#

Answer (score 0):

conflict with TM_CatalogConfigurableSwatches... Solved